# Android 6.0+: how to catch click on 'accept' or 'refused' button of geolocation authorization alert?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-play-services

I use the following code to know if the user granted the geolocation permission and display an alert if it is not the case:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1);

        }
```

So requestPermissions displays a system alert asking the user if he is ok with the use of its geolocation by the app.

What I want is to detect the click on the buttons "yes" or "no" of this alert in order to launch specific actions in both cases.

Is there a way to to this ? Or a workaround ?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of which question? :)

Comment: Look at the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` override in the answer on the linked question, that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't see any linked question :)

Comment: It's at the top....

Comment: Ok ! I did not see it !